# экономическая статистика

Tags: excel, excel-формулы

Как решить в экселе этапами с формулами задачу(написать как её решить): При производстве керамических изделий была выявлена зависимость уровня брака от влажности используемой массы. Линейный коэффициент корреляции составил 0,69, корреляцион-ное отношение - 0,78, общее число наблюдений - 50. При расчете корреляционного отношения были выделены четыре группы, на которые был разделен диапазон факторного признака.
Определить, возможно ли применение линейного уравнения регрессии, если использовать показатель ∞? при вероятности 0,95.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.